# flatbuffers c++ convert from buffer to object only available for root_type (whilst java has all)

Tags: java, c++, flatbuffers

According to flatbuffers sample, on c++, GetMonster function is generated as monster is defined as root_type. 
Obviously 1 schema can only have 1 root_type. which limited that only 1 type per schema can be direct converted from buf to obj. same as UnPack

While for java, every type defined in schema has function "getRootAs..." generated, which is very convenient. every type can be easily converted from ByteBuffer directly.

So, on network game use case with c++, there are lot of types to send over network without direct relationship. 
are we supposed to define one schema files per each type? in order to have the Get / Unpack generated?

P.S. I understand I can do it myself by

```
auto nonRootCustomTypeObj = flatbuffers::GetRoot<NonRootCustomType>(fbb.GetBufferPointer());
```

but wondering why don't such Get/Unpack conversion function available to all type but only root_type in c++ specifically?

Answer (score 0):

This is simply how the APIs turned out, as Java templates don't have the same abilities as C++. Like you said, if you want to use multiple roots, you use the templated version.

Comment: Just I don't understand why there is such difference across diff language or if there is any specific reason for such design, and the purpose of root_type.

Comment: `root_type` is also used as a way to identify what to parse as the root in JSON. But other than that it is mainly due to differences in languages, as I said.